# Mysql Regexp with array

Tags: mysql, arrays, regex

I am getting an array of category id eg. ['1','2','3']
and in my database table it is stored as 1_abc eg : category : 1_Sameer
Now it is easy if i get one value

```
ie. WHERE category like 1_%;
```

But since this is an array how can i use like or regex to compare with the database values

Comment: if all category pattern same then `LIKE` is enough

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can do as many queries as you have array elements and merge these results together if needed to get single collection of elements.

```
$results = new Collection();
foreach($ids as $id) {
$categories=Category::where("id","like","$id_%")->get();
    $results=$results->merge($categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do looping for that

for($i=0;$i<=count($array_result)-1;$i++)
{

$result=mysql_query("select * from table_name where category like  '{$array_result[$i]}_%' ");

}